# Show that one bijection is the inverse of the other bijection if the two (non-identity) bijections commute

Tags: inverse-function

Suppose you have two bijections $\eta, \alpha: S \to S$. Both are not the identity maps on $S$, and that

$$\eta\alpha = \alpha\eta$$

Can we conclude that $\alpha = \eta^{-1}$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried any examples? There's already a counterexample on a set with three elements ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber I tried the three element example but I guess I missed it

Comment: You can always take $\eta = \alpha$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you! I missed that too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following uses [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation).*

Certainly not: consider $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and take both $\alpha$ and $\eta$ to be the permutation $(123)$. Then $\alpha\eta=\eta\alpha$ but $\alpha\not=\eta^{-1}$.

Even if we require $\alpha\not=\eta$ there are still counterexamples; take $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$, let $\alpha=(12)$, and let $\eta=(34)$.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I missed these...

Comment: @Shawn: in general, fixing $\alpha$, the set of $\eta$ such that $\eta \alpha = \alpha \eta$ is called the *centralizer* of $\alpha$. It is always a subgroup, and always contains every power of $\alpha$, but typically contains other elements too.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the maps $f$ and $g$ of the plane defined by $f(x,y) = (-x,y)$ and $g(x,y) = (x,-y)$. These are bijections, they commute, yet are not inverses.